# What are the options for using Xamarin with blazor (webassembly)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Historically we've created cross platform xamarin apps as hybrid apps using a webview and an MVC like framework to create our views (using razor) and process user actions. This worked, and keeps things neat (and seemed quicker and easier than going down the xamarin forms route). However, it seemed fairly quirky and goes against the grain somewhat.

For a project we're working on we've created a lot of web functionality using Blazor (webassembly). We now have the need to create a partner app for mobile devices. In the first instance there will be little crossover between the web UI and the app UI, but they will use the same webapi calls and objects. For the mobile app it makes little sense to revert to the old MVC like framework, when we could do all UI much more neatly in Blazor webassembly. Is this a viable route? I could see it working in the following ways:

Experimental mobile bindings: I've read about the experimental mobile Blazor bindings, but the word experimental is putting me off.

Using a webview- to me this looks like the most simple route, creating a Blazor webassembly and distributing it as a resource, then the app is simply a webview which displays the web assembly. The flaw in this plan will be sharing the data between different views (and getting the nav working), and between the app and the webassembly (ie login details), as they will be in different contexts.

Are either of those viable? Or am I totally missing something. The big concern is that the app will be added to and expanded over the next few years, so we need to ensure we don't use something which becomes legacy quickly (or something we can easily migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the https://jspuij.github.io/BlazorWebView.Docs/pages/androidtutorial.html?tabs=addandroid-3 project

This tutorial is for creating an Android project running a blazor webassembly

Basically you Create a Blazor Project, A Razor Classlib with Pages, Components, an static content and Android Project.

Using the BlazorWebView Nuget Package you can render the Blazor Webassembly project